# Ba'al Shem Tov, King and Nation

Tags: sources-mekorot

Rabbi David Aaron said that the *Ba’al Shem Tov* says in *Parshas Yisro*, והעולם הזה צורך גבוהה - *This world is of great heavenly need.”* כי אין מלך בלא עם - *“For there is no King without a Nation.*
Go [alephbeta.org - time duration 3:58](https://alephbeta.org/course/lecture/believing-is-receiving)

Where is the source for this?

Comment: Please [edit] in where you got this quotation.

Comment: What do I need to edit?

Comment: please [edit] this question post to include as much information as you have about where you found this quotation and why you want to find its source. This will make the question more answerable and will also help readers and answerers best understand why they would want to find/know the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is found in [Keser Shem Tov Part 2 400b - Kehot](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/bsht/kst/2/400b).

It is quoted (with attribution to Keser Shem Tov part 2, 20a, which would reference a different print) in [Baal Shem Tov Al HaTorah Yisro 44](https://www.sefaria.org/Baal_Shem_Tov,_Yitro.44.1).

The source for this statement (of אין מלך בלא עם - there is no King without a Nation) is R[abbeinu Bechaya to Vayeshev 38:30](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42322&st=&pgnum=114&hilite=) and the beginning of Balak. This idea is found in [Pirkei DeRabbi Eliezer 3](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%99_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%92), with slightly different wording.

Comment: Is 400b the page number?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah, yeah (well, 400, I think it is column b, I would have to check a physical copy to be sure - it is very edition specific, that reference would be to the Kehot print).

Comment: Yishai, can you please send me the links to Keser Shem Tov part 2 [20a], Baal Shem Tov Al HaTorah Yisro 44 and Rabbeinu Bechaya to Vayeshev 38:30?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah, I checked a physical copy of Baal Shem Tov Al HaTorah. The Keser Shem Tov 20a page number is what it lists there, I couldn't even guess what edition it is talking about, and I don't think Hebrewbooks.org has it. It is all the same as the existing link in terms of language and context. I'll add the Rabbeinu Bechaya link.

Comment: Who's the author of Baal Shem Tov Al HaTorah? (i.e. the physical copy that you looked through)

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah, Shimon Menachem Mendel of Gorbatchov, with additional research credit credit to Nassan Natta of Kaliver (brothers, if I read that right).