# Ba'al Shem Tov online

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, chasidut-hasidism

Hebrew books does not have Ba'al Shem Tov on the Torah. Does anyone know where I can find the *Ba'al Shem Tov on the Torah* online?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Maybe this link would be helpful:](http://www.ot-tora.com/%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%A9%D7%9D-%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94/)

Its not scanned, so I dont know how reliable it is, but it seems like they typed all the Ba'al Shem Tov on the Torah text to this page...

Hope it helps :)

Comment: For what the specific quote the OP was seeking [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45136/baal-shem-tov-king-and-nation) it is accurate, so it seems to be reliable.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah If this is the correct answer, maybe you should click the green check mark next to it to show that it worked for you ("accept" the answer)